# regex of employee provident fund (epfo)

Tags: regex, xampp

PF Number would be in below mentioned format:

XX/12345/7654321

XX - Represents State in which PF office is located

12345 - Establishment Code

7654321 - Account Number

Detailed explanation:
XX- The 1st two characters are alphabets representing the state in which your PF office is located.
12345- The next characters enclosed between two slashes( /12345/) is establishment code
1234567- the last set of number is account number of an employee

Comment: And what is exactly the question?

Comment: actually i need a regex validation according to this pattern since i am a new user therefor its hard for me to make it  and this is what i make ^([A-Z](/)\d{5}(/)\d{7})*$

Comment: Do the estblishment codes and account number have any limits in length (min,max)? Or have an exact length? They are completely numeric as I understand?

Comment: same limit as showing for instance-2(alphabetical)/5(numeric)/7(numeric)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then this is your friend:

```
 ^[A-Z]{2}/\d{5}/\d{7}$
```

A sequence of exactly two uppercase letter followed by a slash followed by a group of 5 digits followed by a slash followed by a group of 7 digits.

The `^` and `$` will ensure that this is the complete string containing nothing else, which is OK for validating the complete string. If you want to know if s string contains such an Id you have to leave them away, and if you wnat to extract it from a string you will have to use capturing groups (enclose the regex in round brackets).

Comment: i'm sorry i could'nt remind u that this code what  i need is either showed valid or empty .so can u implement it sir or it will be right like ^([A-Z]{2}/\d{5}/\d{7})*$

Comment: The solution I gave you is perfectly fit for validating.

Comment: suppose if we not feel the need of this epfo number i want it to let them empty so what will be the regex for that manner?eg.-either valid or empty

Comment: You can check that before applying the regex? Or you have to do something like `^([A-Z]{2}/\d{5}/\d{7})|[]$` (the given regex or nothing).